# How to automate mysql backups?

Tags: cron-jobs, crontab, cron, svn

I want to automatize the backup of my databases and files with cron.
Should I add the following lines to crontab ?

```
mysqldump -u root -pPASSWORD database_name | gzip > /home/backup/database_`date +\%m-\%d-\%Y`.sql.gz

svn commit -m "Committing the working copy containing the database dump"
```

1) First of all, is this a good approach?
2) It is not clear how to specify the repository and the working copy with svn.
3) How can I run svn only when the mysqldump is done and not before ? Avoiding conflicts

Any other tip ?
thanks

Comment: If you are using a public svn server please consider encrypting the backups with GPG before committing.

Comment: @João Pinto Thanks for tip. It is a private one..

Comment: Is there a good reason for you to use svn to store the backups ? I don't see any benefit from using a revision control system to manage a single binary file.

Comment: MySQL dumps are not binary, but a text file with all the SQL statements (CREATE TABLE, INSERT, etc...) needed to recreate the database.

Comment: @João Pinto I'm using SVN to make backup of several folders and I need somehow to include the database as well. So I'm making a dump and committing it as file.

Comment: @Patrick, ah ok, it makes sense now ;)

Comment: @Javier The dumps themselves are plaintext but when they're piped through `gzip`, they're binary *enough* to not really be worth storing in a VCS.

Comment: Uppss.. Your rigth Oli.

Comment: Are there any security issues with this? A lot of crontab files are rwxr-xr-x which would mean your MySQL passwords are readable. Am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) The mysql dump for backup itself is the usual approach, I don't see any benefit from using svn to store the backups

2) Better move this to it's own question (svn related)

3) By doing the commands in sequence in a script you are already enforcing that, the svn commit is only executed after the mysqldump | gzip finishes .